# why array's initial refcount is 2 in php7.1

Tags: php, arrays, xdebug

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
$b = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
unset($b);
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
```

This will output

```
a: (refcount=2, is_ref=0)=array (2 => (refcount=0, is_ref=0)=1, 1 =>(refcount=0, is_ref=0)=2)
a: (refcount=3, is_ref=0)=array (2 => (refcount=0, is_ref=0)=1, 1 => (refcount=0, is_ref=0)=2)
a: (refcount=2, is_ref=0)=array (2 => (refcount=0, is_ref=0)=1, 1 => (refcount=0, is_ref=0)=2)
```

why in first line the refcount is 2

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be due to "Internal value representation in PHP 7".

Follow this comment in [Reference Counting Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php#122283) on the PHP manual.

And the detailled informations in the [nikic's Blog](https://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html#zvals-in-php-7) : "Zvals in PHP 7".

Please, see also this [xdebug commit on github](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/commit/6aa5307ad8ccb5c6c76b54718c0da6a46a89d8fb). It might also be a part of an answer.